# Two cases brackets in one line, aligned to a formula in a second line

Tags: align, cases, alignat

I am trying to align two cases environments to a formula:

schematically:

```
A = B        +C

  = {cases1  +{cases2
```

where B+cases1 and C+cases2 are aligned.

I read about the `\alignat{3}` option, but I can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
&A = &&  B +&& C\\
&    &&\begin{cases} a1 &&\mbox{if } i \equiv j \\ a2 && \mbox{if } i \not\equiv j \end{cases} + \begin{cases} b1 && \mbox{if } i \equiv j \\ b2 &&\mbox{if } i \not\equiv j \end{cases}
\end{alignat*}
```

Error: `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr`

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error comes from having two `&` in each `cases` environment, there should only be one.

Here is a suggestion:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
A &=  B &&+ C\\
  &=\begin{cases} a1 &\mbox{if } i \equiv j \\ a2 & \mbox{if } i \not\equiv j \end{cases} &&+ \begin{cases} b1 & \mbox{if } i \equiv j \\ b2 &\mbox{if } i \not\equiv j \end{cases}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, now i get it, the &'s in the cases environment do not need a counterpart outside of the cases environment, they are only there to make sure everything is aligned within the cases environment.
That would have taken ages for me to find out!!

Comment: Sorry, I think i accidentally removed a comment :-(

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `stackengine` approach.

REVISED:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\def\stackalignment{l}
A  
\stackunder[8pt]{{}= B}{
{}=\begin{cases} a1 &\mbox{if } i \equiv j \\ a2 & \mbox{if } i \not\equiv j \end{cases}}
\stackunder[8pt]{{}+ C}{
{}+\begin{cases} b1 & \mbox{if } i \equiv j \\ b2 &\mbox{if } i \not\equiv j \end{cases}} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]